# Need Help getting this Error - UserProfileViewController.swift:19:43: Type 'UIStoryboard' has no member 'profileContainerViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error:

> UserProfileViewController.swift:19:43: Type 'UIStoryboard' has no member 'profileContainerViewController'

```
import UIKit

class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    var profileContainerController: ProfileContainerViewController!

    @IBOutlet weak var placeHolderView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.profileContainerController = UIStoryboard.profileContainerViewController()
        self.profileContainerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.addChildViewController(self.profileContainerController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.profileContainerController.view)
        self.profileContainerController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.title = "Profile"
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "profile-icon")
    }
```

many thanks

[Here is the file that is coming up with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUAK2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing something, you're trying to access to something that `UIStoryboard` don't have. What you can do it is something like this to achieve what do you want:

```
class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    // rest of your class
} 

// The private modifier is to allow visibility only inside the scope of the file, if you want to see it in all the project remove it
private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { 
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) 
    }

    class func profileContainerViewController() -> ProfileContainerViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileContainerViewController") as? ProfileContainerViewController
    }
}
```

Of course always remembering you should set the **Storyboard ID** in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder to the name `"ProfileContainerViewController"` for example as I did in the above code.

[image]

I hope this help you.

Comment: thanks a lot Victor Sigler, that solved the error. but now I'm getting a different error which says UIStoryboard.swift:11:11: Use of undeclared type 'UIStoryboard'

Comment: It's strange, where exactly do you have this error?

Comment: in UIStoryboard.swift

Comment: Uhmm... Why do you have a file `UIStoryboard.swift`?, this is a class defined in iOS , you should be careful with that, change the name of the file to another one and test it again, the file not need to have the same name can be called Extensions.swift for example

Comment: I changed the file name but keep getting the same error. just added a screen shot

Comment: Can you share your project in Github to see it?

Comment: Let me check it out a moment

Comment: I checked the repo but I don't have any error, try to share your code instead to check it out, why are you're trying to fix exactly

Comment: does the application build and run ?

Comment: the error UIStoryboard.swift:11:11: Use of undeclared type 'UIStoryboard'

Comment: Ye it's working fine, it have errors related to iOS 9 and WatchConnectivity but not regarding the `UIStoryboard.swift`

Comment: that's odd when I run it on my mac using xcode i get loads of different errors

Comment: what if you get the following error :diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation. appreciate the help

Comment: @adam Just make `pod install` again to fix it :), it should be dissapear the next time you open the project and make a Clean + Build